# Should I post this question in workplace.stackexchange or softwareengineering.stackexchange or elsewhere

Tags: discussion

I have a question about my The Workplace Stack Exchange post: [App startup founder wants my help to solve urgent software engineering problem affecting considerable percent of users - says will give a token sum](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/133254/app-startup-founder-wants-my-help-to-solve-urgent-software-engineering-problem-a)

Answer (score 1):

On the surface,  this is a freelancing question. They might accept it.

But,  if it boils down to "client is lowballing a job", then they might not even accept it there. It ultimately comes down to whether you would except the lowball offer or not for the work.

Answer (score -2):

Looks like a suitable Workplace question to me!